# (Excel Source) File Processing SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005

Tags: excel, visual-studio, oledb, ssis-2017

We are using an excel connection to process files in SSIS (Visual Studio Community 2017) and the process was running well into all of it sudden it stopped processing our files. We have disabled the containers related to excel file processing and unsure how to solve the issue. Can anyone please help? Thank you in advance!

- Excel file format is Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet
- We connect the file path to a SharePoint file
- Excel Connection Manager > ConnectionString is reading

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[File path].xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES";

Execution error log:

1. [Excel Source [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
2. [Excel Source [2]] Error: Opening a rowset for "'INSZoom_Client$'" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.
3. [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Excel Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC02020E8.

- I have verified the that file path is correct in the data source task and connection manager
- Double check that the file name follows the same labeling
- Verified that the columns (name, data type) in the file match the column names in the EDW table